# Applying The Same Criteria Over Many Columns to Compute a New Column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr

I have a dataframe similar to the one below except I have 17 Variables (like `Var1` and `Var2`) instead of 2.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
          "STUD_ID       Var1   Var2
                 1          0      0
                 1          0      1
                 2          1      2
                 3          3      0", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to create a new column that outputs a "Yes" if any of the 17 variables has values 1, 2 or 3, and "No" otherwise. My desired output is:

```
# STUD_ID       Var1   Var2  Output
#       1          0      0    "No"
#       1          0      1   "Yes"
#       2          1      2   "Yes"
#       3          3      0   "Yes"
```

I tried the following code but it gives the error and I would not want to copy-paste part of the code 17 times:

```
df %>%
  mutate(output = if_else(var1 %in% 1:3 |
                          var2 %in% 1:3, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `base R`

```
df$Output <- c("No", "Yes")[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], `%in%`, 1:3)) + 1]
df$Output
#[1] "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes"
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches("Var")), funs(. %in% 1:3)) %>%
    select(-STUD_ID) %>% 
    reduce( `|`) %>% {c('No', 'Yes')[. + 1]} %>% 
    mutate(df, output = .)
#   STUD_ID Var1 Var2 output
#1       1    0    0     No
#2       1    0    1    Yes
#3       2    1    2    Yes
#4       3    3    0    Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to try to do this as vectorized as possible (but still not as efficient as it converts to strings) is to use `do.call` to paste the rows and `grepl` the values you need, i.e.

```
ifelse(grepl('1|2|3', do.call(paste0, df[-1])), 'Yes', 'No')
#[1] "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be the following:

```
df$Output = sapply(seq(1,nrow(df)), 
          function(x) {ifelse(any(df[x,c(2:3)] %in% c(1,2,3)),"Yes","No")})
```

You can replace `c(2:3)` with the range of your column indices, or an array with column names. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the 17 variables, and if sum is greater than 0, then it means atleast one non zero value was there

```
> df$VarNew=df$Var1+df$Var2
> df
  STUD_ID Var1 Var2 VarNew
1       1    0    0      0
2       1    0    1      1
3       2    1    2      3
4       3    3    0      3
> df$VarNew2=ifelse(df$VarNew>0,"Yes","No")
> df
  STUD_ID Var1 Var2 VarNew VarNew2
1       1    0    0      0      No
2       1    0    1      1     Yes
3       2    1    2      3     Yes
4       3    3    0      3     Yes
```

Comment: Assuming the numbers are non-negative and the positive values are only in {1,2,3}, then a one liner would be `ifelse(rowSums(df[-1]) > 0,"Yes", "No")`.